# Multiple Fields For Node Data

Tags: entities, nodes

I am creating a content type for events.  One of the parts of data I want to have is for speakers.  With the speakers I want to have their name, image, company, and bio.  I want to be able to more than one speaker similar to a multivalue text field where you can simply click add another item.

Can this be done in Drupal 7, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Field collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module which lets you the possibility the regroup multiple fields (name, image, company, bio) into one collection (speaker). On that collection, you can put the `number of values` to unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
in event content type create a text field *speaker* and in the setting if this field there is a drop down list which specifies number of values, set it to unlimited. in this way you can have any number of speakers

you are not done yet! create another content type called speaker and add any field that speakers may have.

create a view of event content type and set relationship between speaker field and speaker content type.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a content type for speakers and add your fields (name, image, company etc).
2. In your events content type add an [entityreference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) field with unlimited values to reference the "speaker" node-type entity.

Having the "speakers" as a node type will allow you to do things such as:

- have a speaker's profile page that lists all events they have
  participated in.
- Have a list of speakers on the events page with links to their full profile pages so that users can learn more about them.

The above can be done by creating a block via views and adding it to a region or, by creating a views attachment field which is displayed as a normal field on the node-type of your choice ([EVA: Entity Views Attachment](https://drupal.org/project/eva)). Since you'll be using views, the data you display is up to you i.e. name, photo, link to profile etc.

Answer (score 0):

In response to this question, Mike Vranckx is technically correct. But other users surfing in here wondering how to get 'Add Additional Item' functionality to a field do not necessarily need a Field Collection to accomplish that.

If you only want to have multiple, dynamic instances of one field...

From the 'Manage Fields' area of the content-type, find the field you want to have multiple instances of and click 'Edit'. At the bottom of that following page, you will see 'Number of Values'. Set it to 'unlimited' in the drop-down and, magically, the 'Add Additional Items' will appear under that field when content editors add nodes with this content-type.